# romove obj from query laravel obj['pivot']

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-permission

my query, I'm using laravel permission spatie.  because I need to show the data it's will return the same format. and don't need to show pivot.
if you see, the pivot is into employes->user->roles->**pivote**

```
public function index()
{
    $resp = Employes::where('estado', 1)
    ->with('user.roles:id,name')
    ->get();

    return  response()->json($resp);
}
```

Response

```
 [
   {
      "employ":"Juan",
      "age":21,
      "user":{
         "id":5,
         "name":"mario maradionio",
         "email":"empleado@gmail.com",
         "tipo_usuario":null,
         "roles":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"root",
               "pivot":{
                  "model_id":5,
                  "role_id":1,
                  "model_type":"App\\User"
               }
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"Alumno",
               "pivot":{
                  "model_id":5,
                  "role_id":2,
                  "model_type":"App\\User"
               }
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "name":"Encargado",
               "pivot":{
                  "model_id":5,
                  "role_id":3,
                  "model_type":"App\\User"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

**Model**
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{   
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
}
```

Using collection it not show the roles, just show one role and de name of role is null

```
[
            'id'         => $this->id,
            'employe'       => $this->name,
            'user' => [
               'id' => $this->id,
               'name' => $this->name,
               'roles' => [
                    'id' => $this->id,
                    'name' => $this->name
               ]
            ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

add hidden attributes in your `Role.php` Model

create a `Role.php` and extends then `Spatie\Permission\Models\Role`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role as BaseRole;

class Role extends BaseRole
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'pivot'
    ];

}
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Comment: if you see, the pivot is into employes->user->roles->pivote, its no work

Comment: for `roles` pivot you need to put this code in `Role.php` model

Comment: but Im using trait **use HasRoles;** model user

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Resource class and return that instead.

```php
public function index()
{
    $employees = Employes::where('estado', 1)
        ->with('user.roles')
        ->get();

    return EmployeeResource::collection($employees);
}
```

You can refer to the docs for creating the Resource: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: if use the Resource::Collection() 
` 'user' => [
               'id' => $this->id,
               'name' => $this->name,
               'roles' => [
                    'id' => $this->id,
                    'name' => $this->name
               ]
            ]
` 
The name of role don´t work, get out null
`"user": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": null,
      "roles": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": null
      }
    }`